# swf file generated with Flex Builder 4.5

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4.5

how can I produce my application with a simple swf file `{myapplication}.swf` ?

My first aim is to integrate this swf to JEE project. But, i have some errors that i should integrate also the following swf files, which are important for the compilation :

- textLayout_2.0.0.232.swf
- framework_4.5.0.20967.swf
- mx_4.5.0.20967.swf
- rpc_4.5.0.20967.swf
- spark_4.5.0.20967.swf
- sparkskins_4.5.0.20967.swf

Can i merge (through the compiler or ...) all these swf files in the unique swf file `{myapplication}.swf` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to combine everything to one SWF, in Flash Builder 4 open up the project properties and choose Flex build Path. You'll see a framework linkage option. Change it from "Runtime shared library" to "Merged into code. This default value was changed when moving from Flex 3 to Flex 4.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4389769/965722

Comment: i found the solution of my problem for days. Thank you for your help any way